# Validate if my app is runnin in my phone or PC

Tags: air, adobe

I am developing an application whit Adobe Air and  i want to know if my application is running  in My PC or  some PHONE.

The next var Shows Windows in my PC  and Android in my Phoe

```
var sistema:String = Capabilities.os;
```

There are  some effective  way of knowing if it runs on PC or Phone ?

Comment: Do you mean for the app to know it's running, whether the app can run, or analytics of who's running your app?

Comment: You publish separate files for PC/Mac, Android, and IOS.  You make .apk for Android devices and .ipa for ipad and iphone.